# comma seperated data from an array of data?

Tags: mysql

I have stored multiple files, it is stored in a table as below with the following data in MySQL:

```
s_id       Name       Value
1          A          4.pdf
1          A          5.png
1          B          8.jpeg
2          C          9.jpg
```

how do I store it into the following format and how do i fetch each data of particular s_id by their name like 4.pdf, 5.png etc?

```
s_id         Column
1          A:4.pdf,5.png,B:8jpeg
2          C:9.jpg
```

How do i get this, please suggest me.

Comment: I guess you are using php as backend?

Comment: yes i am using php

Comment: Hey there! Did you find the solution for your problem??

Comment: yes i got that...